Why doesn't Android Studio recognize some of my resources when source sets are nested
I was getting gradle warning that resources should not be needed so I reorganized files and source sets to comply, but when I try to run without the app/res folder I get errors.

This is the warning


Task :app:generateRogueReleaseResources
Nested resources detected.


src\main\res
-- src\main\res\common
-- src\main\res\drawable
-- src\main\res\font
-- src\main\res\layout
-- src\main\res\menu
-- src\main\res\mipmap
-- src\main\res\raw
-- src\main\res\values
-- src\main\res\xml

Nested resources means you have layout like this:
res.srcDirs = [
'src/main/res/',
'src/main/res/category1'
]
However, you should use following structure instead:
res.srcDirs = [
'src/main/res/common',
'src/main/res/category1',
'src/main/res/category2'
]

This is how my app stores resources


This is part of the error output and code in Android manifest
ERROR: C:\Projects\AndroidProjects\Hoot\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\rogueRelease\processRogueReleaseManifestForPackage\AndroidManifest.xml:20: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/howl (aka com.tylerhosting.hoot.rogue:mipmap/howl) not found.
<application
android:name="com.tylerhosting.hoot.hoot.Hoot"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:appComponentFactory="android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory"
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/howl"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="false"
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="false"
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/roundhowl"



Start by getting rid of the common directory, as there is no resource type by that name. After that, please note that your error is about the rogue module, and your screenshot is from some other module.

Using common is part of the warning I got. That's why I added it. I'll try deleting it. Also, the screenshot is for [main] while building rogue. The Rogue variant only has an Android manifest modification.

Concerning the common directory. You can add a resource directory by right clicking on src/main/res to get alternate resources. But there is also an option to add a directory. From that there is a drop-down list of directories to choose from excluding the ones you already have. The common directory was the last one there when I added it. Why would it be there?

I have no idea, sorry.

I figured out the directory listing. AS includes the list of directories declared in Gradle.

There are no build.gradle sourceSets provided, but this can be taken literal:

Nested resources means you have layout like this:
res.srcDirs = [ 'src/main/res/', 'src/main/res/category1' ]


However, you should use following structure instead:
res.srcDirs = [ 'src/main/res/common', 'src/main/res/category1', 'src/main/res/category2' ]


With multiple source directories, the parent directory must not be a list item.
And one can't just create randomly named directories inside src/main/res.
It maybe should build, when removing parent src/main/res from this list;However, src/main/res/common should not even be there, to begin with.
Source-set main is as "common" as it can get already;
maybe instead create a library module :common?
Inside the same module this makes no sense.

Reread the post. The question above shows the warning when I include src/main/res. Below that is the error message I get when I take it out.

I didn't include build.gradle sourceSets because the warning shows it.

The error message doesn't show the code which produces the error - and if you're trying to build some nostalgic project, this may eventually build with a matching version of Gradle & AGP. Just see which AGP version it uses, then download the matching version of Android Studio from archive.

The highlighted code is in the merged Android manifest where I declare icon (        android:icon="@mipmap/howl") and others. it's not a nostalgic project. I'm just trying to comply with requirements of Gradle 9.0 before I have to use it.
